# Oracle Index Rebuild Job

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am newly working on Oracle. our DB hit by thousands of DML every 5 mins, so after some time it throws an error for rebuild index. Please some one suggest me to how can i setup a job for rebuild all indexes regularly.
I am using Oracle SQL developer 4.2.
Oracle 11g

Comment: What is this "error for rebuild index" exactly?

Comment: Are these standard (b-tree) indexes?  If so, see Oracle support note 989093.1.  Key quote: _"Generally speaking, the need to rebuild b-tree indexes is very rare"_.  There are many myths to the contrary.